# Unchecked Cast Warning with Comparable Interface and Generic List

Tags: java, list, generics, comparable

I'm getting an unchecked cast warning when I use a Comparable interface with a generic or parametized List. I'm able to do the comparison using an ObjectList but not with a generic list. Here's my development, first with an ObjectList and then with a generic List.

Here's a snippet of my ListNode class definition:

```
public class ListNode {
    private Object info;
    private ListNode next;
```

and a snippet of my ObjectList class definition:

```
public class ObjectList {
    private ListNode list;
```

and my Comparable interface:

```
public interface Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o);
}
```

I have a method in my ObjectList class that compares an Object parameter with an Object in a ListNode with no problem. Here's the comparison code:

```
if (((Comparable)o).compareTo(p.getInfo()) == 0)
```

I'm now trying to create a generic List class and do a similar comparison. Here's a snippet of my generic ListNode class definition:

```
public class ListNode<Type> {
    private Type info;
    private ListNode<Type> next;
```

and a snippet of my generic List class definition:

```
public class List<Type> {
    private ListNode<Type> list;
```

and my generic Comparable interface:

```
public interface Comparable<Type> {
    public int compareTo(Type t);
}
```

I get the unchecked cast warning below from my generic List class when I attempt the same comparison as with my ObjectList class:

List.java:239: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : Type
required: Comparable

```
if (((Comparable<Type>)t).compareTo(p.getInfo()) == 0)
```

Any thoughts?

Here's some simplified code:

```
public class List<Type> {
    public class ListNode<Type> {
        private Type info;
        private ListNode<Type> next;

        public ListNode() {
            info = null;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    private ListNode<Type> list;

    public List() {
        list = null;
    }

    public boolean contains(Type t) {
        ListNode<Type> p = list;
        while (p != null && (((Comparable<Type>)t).compareTo(p.info) != 0))
            p = p.next;
        return p != null;
    }
}



public interface Comparable<Type> {
        public int compareTo(Type t);
}
```

Adding a bounded parameter to the list class:

```
public class List<Type extends Comparable<Type>> {
```

solves the warning issue. But creating a list of String objects produces this error:

type parameter java.lang.string is not within its bound

Comment: t would be declared in some client code: 
        List<String> sList = new List<String>();

Comment: Not using JDK. Developing generic List for presentation to my class.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to create your own `Comparable` interface while there is already one in JDK?  The reason for fail to create List of String is simply because String didn't bear your own Comparable interface.  It has only implemented java.lang.Comparable.  Just do some rename and things will be clear: what you are doing is:

```
public interface MyComparable<Type> {
    public int compareTo(Type t);
}

public class MyList<Type extends MyComparable<Type>> {
  //....
}
```

and then you are trying to create a `MyList<String>` variable

`String` is not implementing `MyComparable`, of course it is causing problem.

Answer (score 1):

First change your List declaration to the code below. This makes it so that the parameterized type must be Comparable.

```
List<Type extends Comparable<Type>>
```

You can then call `t.compareTo(p.info)` directly without the cast. Second, move your ListNode class to its own file.

Comment: ListNode class is in own file. Just showed as inner class to simplify. Added bounded parameter as suggested and omitted the unneeded casts. No warning messages anymore. However, instantiating a simple List of Strings in main() produces an error: type parameter java.lang.String is not within its bound:         List<String> sList = new List<String>();

Comment: Are you trying to use your own Comparable interface? If you want to use String then you have to use java.lang.Comparable. Otherwise you will have to make your own String class. I don't have the full context here, but it seems like you are reproducing a lot of built in functionality: List, Comparable, etc.

Comment: for best results use `Type extends Comparable<? super Type>`